# There are no simple groups of order $56$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

I was reading a proof about this http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~clein/427_inclass_solutions.pdf

Can someone explain to me why "all Sylow $2$–subgroups must have order $8$"?

Answer (score 3):

> **Definition.**
>   Let $|G|=p^\alpha m$ where $p$ is a prime and $(p,m)=1$. Then a subgroup of order $p^\alpha$ is called a Sylow $p$-subgroup.

Since $|G|=2^3 7$ and $(2,7)=1$, a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G$ has order $2^3=8$.